# Folding a list with accumulating into an array

Tags: arrays, haskell

I'm trying to implement counting sort using arrays.

Input: count_of_elements "\n" (array_element " "){n}

All array_element are in [1..10]

I've written the following code:

```
import Data.Array
import Data.List

toIntLst :: String -> [Int]
toIntLst = map read . words 

main = do
  getLine
  y <- getLine
  let nums = toIntLst y
  let arr = array(1,10) [(i, 0) | i <- [1..10]] 
  let sum_arr = foldl (\acc x -> arr//[(x, (arr ! x) + 1)]) arr nums
  let result = concat $ map (\x -> replicate (sum_arr ! x) x) $ indices sum_arr
  print nums
  print sum_arr
  print result
```

I misunderstood why the result of folding names to sum_arr didn't meet my expectations (I expected that array would contain occurrences of all elemens). The resulting array equal to an array which can be gotten by dropping out all except last elements of nums and then do the same fold.

P.S. Could you tell me whether Haskell's array access time is O(1)? I haven't found this information here: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-Array.html and unusual interface of array confused me.

Comment: try specifying `arr`'s type explicitly as unboxed array, you might see a significant speedup: `let arr :: UArray Int Int; arr = array (1,10) ...`. `import Data.Array.Unboxed` for that. Compile with -O2 flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile with `-Wall`, then you'll see the problem:

> runhaskell -Wall /tmp/wtmpf-file15704.hs
>   
>   /tmp/wtmpf-file15704.hs:2:1: Warning:
>       The import of `Data.List' is redundant
>         except perhaps to import instances from `Data.List'
>       To import instances alone, use: import Data.List()
>   
>   /tmp/wtmpf-file15704.hs:7:1: Warning:
>       Top-level binding with no type signature: main :: IO ()
>   
>   /tmp/wtmpf-file15704.hs:8:3: Warning:
>       A do-notation statement discarded a result of type String.
>       Suppress this warning by saying "_ <‌- getLine",
>       or by using the flag -fno-warn-unused-do-bind
>   
>   /tmp/wtmpf-file15704.hs:12:25: **Warning: Defined but not used: `acc'**

---

Regarding your PS: Array access is *O*(1), yes. But only for reading of course; updating a single element generally necessitates copying the entire array.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Very stupid mistake :(
I'm sorry for the question.

Answer (score 2):

You accidentally used `arr` instead of `acc` in the step function.  Try changing it to this:

```
let sum_arr = foldl (\acc x -> acc//[(x, (acc ! x) + 1)]) arr nums
```

As a side note, you should always use the strict left fold (Data.List.foldl') instead of the lazy one.